# Netfilter not changing destination

Tags: networking, iptables

I am intercepting packets as they are being routed through a certain server P.
I have a client and server, A and B respectively, who are taking to each other.

Basically, I want to be able to, when P gets a packet from A (destined for B), to turn the packet round and modify it (into an ACK).

I am modifying the source and destination addresses of the ip packet successfully but when I then release the packet back, it is still going to B even when the IP packet is marked with destination of A.

So in summary, what I want is:

```
A----->(src=A, dest=B) -----> P ------------------B

A-----<(src=B, dest=A) -----< P ------------------B
```

But what I get is:

```
A----->(src=A, dest=B) -----> P ------------------B

A ------------- P >-------(src=B, dest=A) ------- > B
```

Why is this the case:

For reference, my iptables command is:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Additionally, When I change my iptables command to:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING ....
```

The Packet seems to dissapear after netfilter accepts it. And wireshark shows the original packet instead of the ACK packet I changed it to

Comment: try at table nat, as the example said: http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-targets-and-jumps.html#NFQUEUETARGET

Comment: Nat table does not work, as the connection would already be established by the time I get a packet I want to modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.

The destination NAT'ing needs to be done in the PREROUTING chain of the mangle table.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING .... -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Additionally, and very importantly, **[rpfilter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) needs to be deactivated**. This was originally dropping the packet after the routing stage.